# How to have a bash script loop until a specific time

Tags: bash, loops, time

Usually to run an infinite bash loop, I do something like the following:

```
while true; do
    echo test
    sleep 1
done
```

What if instead, I want to do a loop that loops infinitely as long as it is earlier than 20:00. Is there a way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `date` to print the hours and then compare to the one you are looking for:

```
while [ $(date "+%H") -lt 20 ]; do
    echo "test"
    sleep 1
done
```

as `date "+%H"` shows the current hour, it keeps checking if we are already there or in a "smaller" hour.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a specific date, not only full hours, then try comparing the Unix time:

```
while [ $(date +%s) -lt $(date --date="2016-11-04T20:00:00" +%s) ]; do
    echo test
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `true` to the real condition:

```
while (( $(date +%H) < 20 )) ; do
    echo Still not 8pm.
    sleep 1
done
```