# Linux Commands Loop

Tags: linux, terminal, operating-system

I want to make a loop in CentOS SSH Terminal where it loops over certain commands. For example:

1. `zmap -p22 -o mfu.txt -B100M -N 250000`

   Waits until that's finished
2. `chmod 777 *`
3. `./update 1500`

   Stops task after 25 mins
4. `perl wget.pl vuln.txt`
5. repeat the process

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to parallelize step 1? Use parallel.
Step 3.*./update* is very broad. Do you want to update dataset/underlying programs? Dump output?
For step 3.*repeating* and step 5.*repeat* you could use something like
[How to have a bash script loop until a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548064/how-to-have-a-bash-script-loop-until-a-specific-time)

Answer (score 0):

For step 5, do you want to repeat the process during a specific time (like step 3), or for a number of iterations ?  For the second option you can do something like (with N iterations):

```
for i in $(seq 1 N); do execute steps 1 to 4; done
```